# Convert SQL to Linq in ASP Net Core

Tags: sql, linq

I learning ASP NET CORE and i have to use LINQ 
and a have to try very much
it more easy with simple query
but with complex query it's so hard

for example i have a sql query

`select Products.ProductId,Products.ProductName,OrderDetails.UnitPrice, sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) as TotalQuantity`

`from
Products, OrderDetails, Orders`

`where Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId`

`and Orders.OrderId=OrderDetails.OrderId`

`and Orders.OrderDate between '1/2/2019' and '12/12/2019'`

`group by Products.ProductId,Products.ProductName,OrderDetails.UnitPrice`

how can i query like this in linq (I tried 2 days but.....!)
thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a database to test against, but try this:

```
from o in Orders
join d in OrderDetails on o.OrderId equals d.OrderId
join p in Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId
where o.OrderDate > Convert.ToDateTime("1/2/2019")
   && o.OrderDate < Convert.ToDateTime("12/12/2019")
group d.Quantity by new {p.ProductId, p.ProductName, d.UnitPrice} into g
select new 
{
    ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
    ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
    UnitPrice = g.Key.UnitPrice,
    TotalQuantity = g.Sum()
}
```

To sum multiple columns adjust the group to just **d**, adjust the existing sum to add **d => d.Quantity** in the parenthesis and add the new sum line like this:

```
from o in Orders
join d in OrderDetails on o.OrderId equals d.OrderId
join p in Products on d.ProductId equals p.ProductId
where o.OrderDate > Convert.ToDateTime("1/2/2019")
   && o.OrderDate < Convert.ToDateTime("12/12/2019")
group d by new {p.ProductId, p.ProductName, d.UnitPrice} into g
select new 
{
    ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
    ProductName = g.Key.ProductName,
    UnitPrice = g.Key.UnitPrice,
    TotalQuantity = g.Sum(d => d.Quantity),
    TotalUnitPrice = g.Sum(d => d.UnitPrice)
}
```

Comment: Thank bro it very useful. you lock like a god, thank you very much

Comment: what should i do if i want to sum UnitPrice
it's solution: group { d.Quantity,d.UnitPrice } by ... ,isn't it?